# How to re-read a Kafka Topic at the reception of an event on Flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

My Flink job listen two Kafka topics (from the beginning) : TopicA and TopicB. When messages arrive from TopicA, the job makes calculations. When messages arrive from TopicB, **I want the job to reset calculations and re-read the TopicA** (from the beginning too).

Is it possible? I did not find solution to re-read a Kafka topic. I have a temporary solution : restart the job thanks to a shell script so that the TopicA be re-read (from the beginning).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you maybe describe your use case so that we find a different solution for the problem?

Comment: My use case : I accumulate values from TopicA. But when a data arrives from TopicB, calculations made from TopicA become false (because the data arrived from TopicA has an influence on the calculation of data from TopicA). So, I need to re-accumulate values from TopicA (from the beginning) **with** the data arrived from the TopicB.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to re-read an entire Kafka topic based on certain events.
Only when starting a Flink job, you can tell the connector to read from the beginning.